# Splitting dataframe and keeping shared columns

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataframe

```
df = data.frame(V1 = 1, V2 = 2, V3 = 3, V4 = 4, V5 = 5, respondent_ID = "ID1", respondent_attribute = "Attribute1")
```

and want to split it into two dataframes, one of which will contain columns V1, V2, V3, respondent_ID and respondent_attribute, and the other will contain V4, V5, respondent_ID and respondent_attribute.

I can do it relatively easily using

```
newdf <- subset(df, select = c(1:3, 6:7))
```

and then manually deleting columns V1, V2, and V3 from df

```
df[1:3] = NULL
```

but I suspect there is a more elegant (and perhaps better practice) solution. Any advice?

Comment: You can just use the form `df[,c(1,2,3,6,7)]` or `df[,c("V1","V2","V3","respondent_ID","respondent_attribute")]` (and similarly for the second one) depending on whether you know the column indices or not

Answer (score 1):

You can have a better control if you do something like this:

```
df = data.frame(V1 = 1, V2 = 2, V3 = 3, V4 = 4, V5 = 5, respondent_ID = "ID1", respondent_attribute = "Attribute1")

# Alternative 1
newdf1 <- df[,c("V1", "V2", "V3", "respondent_ID", "respondent_attribute")]
newdf2 <- df[,c("V4", "V5", "respondent_ID", "respondent_attribute")]

# Alternative 2
newdf1 <- df[,c(1:3, 6:7)]
newdf2 <- df[,c(4:5, 6:7)]
```

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: I suppose it makes sense. Your approach also works with `newdf1 <- df[,c(1:3, 6:7)]`, which is useful for dealing with large dataframes.